# Linux check dependencies of executable

Tags: linux, docker, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently struggling with getting an executable to run inside a Docker container for work. When I try to run it I just get the following error `bash: no such file or directory: ./[executable_name]`

I know that just running `sudo apt install lsb` would fix the issue, as that is fixing the issue on the WSL2 version of Ubuntu. However, the specific Docker image I have to work with (debian bullseye) does not have an installation candidate for `lsb`. `lsb-core` also fulfills this dependency, however also isn't available.

I know that I can check for dependencies using the `ldd` command, however it shows all dependencies as satisfied.

```
ldd [executable_name]
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce612c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdfb401e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdfb3ffb000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdfb3e09000)
    /lib64/ld-lsb-x86-64.so.3 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdfb402f000)
```

(Well, there is no location for `linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce612c000)`, [but as far as I understand that shouldn't be the issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476971/ldd-shows-no-location-after-arrow-library-does-not-exist-on-system))

I don't even know if the issue lies with missing `lsb`/`lsb-core`, or some dependencies they require. Is there any convenient way for me to figure out what dependencies are missing beyond just trial and error installing the dependencies of `lsb-core` one by one, to see which one actually is needed?

Edit: Yes, I am aware that this looks an issue with me not using the correct path/file permissions, however I can guarantee you, that this is not the case. I've tripple checked the path, verified it with `ls`, and verified the file permissions with `ls -l`.

Comment: From the error it seems like you're not even calling your executable at all, since bash cannot find it. Either you're in the wrong directory or didn't copy it into the container.

Comment: That's not the issue. At first I thought that as well, however
A) this is the exact error I get on my Ubuntu when the `lsb` is not installed
B) `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1145845 Nov  8  2021 [executable_name]` is the output of `ls -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oooooooookay, that's not strictly an answer to the initial question, aka on how to figure out which specific library I'm missing, however I fixed my specific issue.

```
sudo apt install alien
wget https://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/altlinux/p10/branch/x86_64/RPMS.classic/lsb-core-5.0-alt1.x86_64.rpm
sudo alien --to-deb -c lsb-core-5.0-alt1.x86_64.rpm
```

And then providing this `*.deb` file to the Docker container and installing it fixed the issue. So I guess it was just `lsb-core` missing, and obtaining the `.rpm` version of it and converting it to the `.deb` format is compatible enough for my usecase!

I stumbled upon this solution thanks to [this wonderful thread.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545540/debian-unable-to-install-lsb-package)